# random number generator using python

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a microservice using `Flask`, that needs to give me a random number.
Unfortunately I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'uniform'

```
import random
from flask import Flask

app: Flask = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def random():
    r1 = random.uniform(0, 10)
    return r1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

new to microservice and python.

Comment: Probably because you shadowed the standard `random` with your own function also called `random`. Change the name of your `def`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you redefined random. You can either change the function name or give alias to imported `random` library.

**Method 1:**
Change the function name you defined.

```
import random
from flask import Flask

app: Flask = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def myRandom():                   //Changed here
    r1 = random.uniform(0, 10)
    return r1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Method 2**
Import `random` using alias.

```
import random as r             //Changed here
from flask import Flask

app: Flask = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def random():
    r1 = r.uniform(0, 10)
    return r1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```